# I have tried installing cpp-httplib but I keep getting a `__imp_freeaddrinfo' error

Tags: c++

I am a beginner to C++, and I was trying to install [cpp-httplib](https://github.com/yhirose/cpp-httplib), but I keep running into these errors:

[image]

My C++ code looks like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "./httplib.h"

int main(void) {
    
  httplib::Server svr;

  svr.Get("/hi", [](const auto &, auto &res) {
    res.set_content("Hello World!", "text/plain");
  });

  std::cout << "start server..." << std::endl;
  svr.listen("0.0.0.0", 8080);
}
```

I have used cmake in the directory, and generated the files, but I don't know what is causing this problem exactly.

Comment: Why `./httplib.h`? Why not just `httplib.h`?

Comment: Googling the function name gives you the library you forgot to link: `-lws2_32`.